Зачем в данном примере используют указатели в Си?
Есть пример программы на Си где копируются данные из одного массива в другой.
#include <stdio.h>

 
int main(){
 

char source[100] = "Source string";
char destination[10]; 

  

const char *src = source;
char *dst = destination;

int max_len_copy = sizeof(destination);

  
while(*src != '\0' && max_len_copy-- > 1)
    *dst++ = *src++;
*dst = '\0';
  

puts(destination);


return 0;

}

И вот вопрос, ЗАЧЕМ использовать указатели на эти массивы, разве нельзя было без них обойтись ?
const char *src = source;
char *dst = destination;

Единственный плюс что я вижу в их использование в данном примере что, не нужно в цикле писать source[i++] и destination[i++].
Можете пожалуйста это мне объяснить!

Конечно, можно использовать индексы. Форма записи в данном случае это дело личного вкуса программиста. Кому-то нравятся индексы, а других просто тошнит от квадратных скобочек. А кто-то вместо *src != '\0' написал бы просто *src. Но если откомпилировать с достаточной оптимизацией, то скорее всего машинный код цикла копирования будет одним и тем же.
